# Flutter how to make midle circle selector?

Tags: flutter, dart, geometry

i need to create a a selector that moves arround a half circle and get the polar coord of to make something.
Then i am using cirlce_list_flutter plugin to make the selector to move, but my problem is that it dindt got an end angle then my selector disappear when it surpasses the half of the circle, both above and below.

[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9CUW.png)

[What i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YhPx.png)

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tftQw.png)
When the outer selector surpass the top angle or bottom it dissapear, i need to make that the selector remains at top or a bottom and dont surpase it.

Some help?